# Videos unavailable when trying to play embedded youtube url (Xamrin.Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, youtube, embed

I'm using Xamarin Android to develop an app for song suggestions and I am using embeded youtube url, and the thing I'm trying to understand is why some videos are playing fine and other are showing error and not playing at all. The error is 'Video Unavailable'.
I found a solution that said to upload the html to a server, but I can't upload it because I change the video dynamically

Thanks.

```
    protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Window.RequestFeature(Android.Views.WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.songSuggestion_layout);
        SetViews();
        categories = new Categories();
        songs = new Songs();
        songSuggsted = new Songs();
        playlist = new Playlist();

        await SetListSongsOfSuggestion();



        var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        //fix video screen height and width
        //intDisplayWidth = (FnConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.WidthPixels) + 200);
        //intDisplayHeight = (FnConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.HeightPixels)) / (2);

        intDisplayHeight = 500;
        intDisplayWidth = 1000;
        PlayInWebView();



    }



    public void PlayInWebView()
    {
         string strUrl = songSuggsted[position].UrlSong;

      //  string strUrl= "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_VsvZmIWxY";
        string id = FnGetVideoID(strUrl);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            strUrl = string.Format("http://youtube.com/embed/{0}", id);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Video url is not in correct format", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            return;
        }
        string html = @"<html><body><iframe width=""videoWidth"" height=""videoHeight"" src=""strUrl""></iframe></body></html>";
        var myWebView = (WebView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.videoView);
        var settings = myWebView.Settings;
        settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
        settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
        settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
        settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
        settings.SetRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.High);
        settings.BuiltInZoomControls = false;

        settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
        myWebView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
        settings.SetPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.On);
        string strYouTubeURL = html.Replace("videoWidth", intDisplayWidth.ToString()).Replace("videoHeight", intDisplayHeight.ToString()).Replace("strUrl", strUrl);

        myWebView.LoadDataWithBaseURL(null, strYouTubeURL, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

    }


    static string FnGetVideoID(string strVideoURL)
    {
        const string regExpPattern = @"youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)/(?:.*v(?:/|=)|(?:.*/)?)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)";
        //for Vimeo: vimeo\.com/(?:.*#|.*/videos/)?([0-9]+)
        var regEx = new Regex(regExpPattern);
        var match = regEx.Match(strVideoURL);
        return match.Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : null;
    }



    int FnConvertPixelsToDp(float pixelValue)
    {
        var dp = (int)((pixelValue) / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
        return dp;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Could you provide a url which throw the error of 'Video Unavailable' for us to test?

Comment: Yes you can use this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hzrDeceEKc or the embedded one "https://www.youtube.com/embed/6hzrDeceEKc"

Comment: It seems you list the items on youtube url and play the video in the link, you could check the sample code on the link below. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/162952/youtube-playlist-in-xamarin-forms-app

Comment: I dont want to show my playlist from youtube , I just want to play one video at a time webview .

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code below:

Create a webview in android layout.

Xaml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.webkit.WebView
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code Behind:

```
 var myWebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
        WebSettings setting = myWebView.Settings;
        setting.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        myWebView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        myWebView.LoadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hzrDeceEKc");
```

[image]

Comment: You could share with us and accept as answer. Thanks~

Comment: So ,there is an easier way to do that , you can use the Xamrin.Youtube.Player and it works fine.
i learned from this site - https://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-youtube-api-to-embed-video-in-an-android-app/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. 
OP asked about Embedded YouTube video, not just url to YouTube website video. Embedded Youtube video uses an iFrame and the "embed" API parameter, which has issues in WebView.